# Rails - after_initialize or initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever my Rails 4 application loads after a deployment, I want to make a REST APi call to another application to tell it my app is ready and kick off some tests.

I was initially going to do this in the initialzers folder, but then I figured that it executes this stuff *while* the app is initializing and the app may not be fully initialized, so if it kicks off some tests, it may fail.

Then I read about the after_initialize, but I'm not sure how to use it and where the code should go to make the rest call after the app is fully loaded?

Can some one help?

Here is the code I want to run when the app has loaded:

```
if Rails.env.dev?
   response = HTTParty.post(the_rest_url,
                  {
                    :basic_auth => @auth
                  })
    puts response.message
```

Comment: If you deploy code with capistrano i recommend to do it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put it in `config/environments/development.rb` as you want it to run in development.

It's outlined in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)

```
config.after_initialize do
  response = HTTParty.post(the_rest_url,
                  {
                    :basic_auth => @auth
                  })
    puts response.message
end
```

> Note that this block will be run for rake tasks

Comment: thanks - could you elaborate on the note about rake tasks? I don't want this to run when rake is performed

Comment: can you put it in a initializer file like this code example?  https://gist.github.com/stevenharman/8590937

Comment: I didn't think you wanted it in an initializer? The note is from the guides.

Comment: from what I was reading, if you have it in an initialzer then use config.after_initialize, it will be ran after the initializers.  See the very bottom of this page which mentions the order in which they are executed.   http://www.sekuda.com/rails_initialization_and_configuration_order  I just want to make sure the app has been loaded first.

Comment: That explains using them in `development.rb` and `production.rb` not an initializer.

Comment: thanks I'll try in the development.rb and see if it works ok